# ASP.Net MVC3 JSON to Model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone lead me to examples showing how to convert incoming JSON to a Model in MVC3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's already handled for you by the framework.

So you define models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Complex Complex { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Complex
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller action taking this model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

and finally you hammer this controller action with a JSON request matching the structure of your view model:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: 1,
        name: 'john smith of course, why asking?',
        complex: {
            id: 3
        },
        foos: [
            { bar: 'the bar' },
            { bar: 'the baz' },
        ]
    }),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('hooray');
    }
});
```

Comment: We decided to make the webservice SOAP. No need for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

I would add more, but the example code is also on that front page.

Comment: I don't want to convert my model TO JSON, I want to convert JSON to my model. I don't see that package doing that.

Comment: You can DEserialize the JSON, then map the data to your model

Comment: Why would you do all that when the framework already handles this for you?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the OP stated "incoming JSON" In my experience, json.NET has handeled this much easier than the DataContractJsonSerializer or JavaScriptSerializer. Here is a really good writeup of someone consuming Stack Overflow's JSON API http://freshbrewedcode.com/jonathancreamer/2012/02/07/using-json-net-to-consume-the-json-stack-overflow-api/

Comment: Who said anything about `DataContractJsonSerializer`? ASP.NET MVC doesn't use that. It uses a `JsonValueProviderFactory` factory based on the `JavaScriptSerializer` class. And everything's already built-in. The link you provided illustrates the client/consuming part, not the server side JSON to view model conversion part which is what I thought the OP was asking about.

Comment: Well, I hope in either case then, either of the two answers helps. Ultimately, you're the MVP ;)